# Pandas - Convert discount factor dataframe to bond-equivalent par yields

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, quantlib

I have a 3-column dataframe representing a daily discount factor curve out 30 years. The columns are [cashflow_day, maturity_dt, discount_factor]. I'd like to return a dataframe with the corresponding par yield curve; daily, out to 29.5 years.

I'm essentially trying to calculate the par yield for a bond that is maturing on every day in my input dataframe, given the input discount factor curve.

So far I have this solution using a handful of QuantLib methods, but am wondering if there's a better way to do this.

To make it clear, **I am definitely a Python and QuantLib novice!!**.

In the code block below, I'm sort of kluging together the code to solve for c in the following equation:

```
A bond is at par if its clean price is equal to par.

P + AI = P*Sum(c*t(i)*D(t(i)),i=1..n) + P*D(t(n))

where:
    P = Par
    AI = Accrued Interest
    c = coupon rate
    t(i) = tau for the i-th cash-flow
    D(t(i)) = discount factor for the i-th cash-flow
```

Please tear this to shreds and let me know how I can do this better. Right now, this runs in ~13 seconds on my machine.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import math
import QuantLib as ql
import time
from datetime import datetime

start = time.time()


# Valuation date
calc_date = ql.Date(30,11,2020)

# Set up dummy data
lamb_gyro = pd.DataFrame({'cashflow_day': range(0,20000)})
lamb_gyro['maturity_dt'] = lamb_gyro.apply(lambda x: calc_date + ql.Period(int(x.cashflow_day), ql.Days), axis=1)

random.seed(a=1)
lamb_gyro['discount_factor'] = lamb_gyro.apply(
    lambda x: math.exp(-random.uniform(0.01,0.09)*x['cashflow_day']/365.25), 
    axis=1
)

discount_curve = ql.DiscountCurve(lamb_gyro.maturity_dt, lamb_gyro.discount_factor, ql.ActualActual())
discount_curve_handle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(discount_curve)

lamb_gyro = lamb_gyro[lamb_gyro.cashflow_day > 1]

# Generate the schedule of cash-flows for each implied bond
lamb_gyro['schedule'] = lamb_gyro.apply(lambda x: ql.MakeSchedule(calc_date, x.maturity_dt, ql.Period('6M')), axis=1)
lamb_gyro['interest_cashflows'] = lamb_gyro.apply(lambda x: ql.FixedRateLeg(x.schedule, ql.ActualActual(), [100.], [.01]), axis=1)
lamb_gyro['sumproduct_tau_discount_factors'] = lamb_gyro.apply(lambda x: ql.CashFlows.npv(x.interest_cashflows, discount_curve_handle, False, calc_date), axis=1)
lamb_gyro['bond'] = lamb_gyro.apply(lambda x: ql.Bond(0, ql.TARGET(), calc_date - ql.Period(1,ql.Years), x.interest_cashflows), axis=1)

lamb_gyro['previous_cash_flow_date'] = lamb_gyro.apply(lambda x: ql.BondFunctions.nextCashFlowDate(x.bond, calc_date) - ql.Period(6,ql.Months), axis=1)

lamb_gyro['accrued_interest_tau'] = lamb_gyro.apply(lambda x: 
    ql.ActualActual().yearFraction(x.previous_cash_flow_date, calc_date), axis=1
)

lamb_gyro['bond_par_yield'] = lamb_gyro.apply(lambda x:
    (1 - x.discount_factor)/(x.sumproduct_tau_discount_factors - x.accrued_interest_tau), axis=1
)

end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

*Edited to remove some unnecessary text*

Comment: too much text with  no MRE , read about MRE in stackoverflow

Comment: Removed a decent chunk of probably unnecessary context. Happy to remove more if it helps.

Comment: you also have to provide a sample of your data so we can work it out ! Thank u

Comment: Any reason why you need to build a dataframe with daily discount factors? If you have a curve object you can just calculate the forward rate for each date in the form of the bond (compounded annual, compounded semi, etc). That rate would be equivalent to the par yield of a bond.

Comment: @DavidDuarte Not necessarily; in the context of what we do, we just need to be able to discount cash-flows on potentially any given day out to a number of years (here it's 30). Previous tools used (SAS) did not have a true function that we could use to just feed an instrument object.
To your second statement; we're not looking to get a par yield for any individual bond, but rather have the full curve specified in terms of par yield, as that's what our internal systems require as an input for their curve. Let me know if I misheard you, though.

Comment: I am unclear ... are you saying your code doesn't work, or that 13 seconds is too long to calculate over 10,000 par yields?

Comment: Fair point ;). When I first posted, I did not have a solution that worked, which is sort of a catch-22 for posting a question. Now I do, but it does take longer than a solution coded up in SAS that runs in <1 second. Not a huge deal, but I'm much more familiar with SAS, so seeing if there was something blatantly obvious I'm missing.